# New content is not inheriting style of parent div with infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, css, inheritance, infinite-scroll

I'm using infinite scroll to load new images into a gallery. The parent div of these images has the style "text-align: justify" to spread the images across the line with equal margins between them. However when the new images are loaded with infinite scroll, the new items appear to be aligned to the left.

HTML (After AJAX content has loaded):

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div id="pagination">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {text-align:justify;}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $('#content').infinitescroll({

        navSelector : "#pagination",            
        nextSelector : "#pagination #next a:first",    
        itemSelector : "#content .item",        
        bufferPx : 5,
        debug : true,
        loading: {
        msgText : " ", 
        img : "loading.gif",
        finishedMsg : " ",
        }  
    });
</script>
```

Using the above code, the first four items are justified, while the last four (after the pagination links) are aligned left. I tried setting #content to "visibility:hidden" as a test, and in that case the new items *did* inherit the visibility property. Can anyone tell me why the "text-align: justify" property is not being inherited? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem too!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Put your `.item` in a wrapper like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="pagination">...</div>
</div>
```

And change your `itemSelector` to `.wrapper` in infinite scroll script like this:

```
<script>
    $('#content').infinitescroll({
        navSelector : "#pagination",            
        nextSelector : "#pagination #next a:first",    
        itemSelector : "#content .wrapper",   //Change .item to .wrapper     
        bufferPx : 5,
        debug : true,
        loading: {
        msgText : " ", 
        img : "loading.gif",
        finishedMsg : " ",
        }  
    });
</script>
```

I think when you wrapped your item in a wrapper and append this wrapper to `#content`, the whitespace will come along with your `.item`. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15258261/1670310), justification relies on whitespace, if you select `.item` to append to `#content`, the whitespace will be remove, this makes `text-align: justify` fail to align your items.